# I was following a spring tutorial to make coronavirus tracker application.but then encountered a problem in parsing using thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

P.S - I just started spring boot
while parsing the file I got this error:

> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
> this as a fallback.
>
> Wed Feb 24 00:20:45 IST 2021 There was an unexpected error
> (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). An error happened during
> template parsing (template: "class path resource
> [templates/home.html]")
> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened
> during template parsing (template: "class path resource
> [templates/home.html]")

This is my home.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

  <head>
    <title>CoronaVirus Tracker Application</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
  
    <p th:text="${testName}"></p>
    
     <table>
      <tr>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Total cases reported</th>
      </tr>
      <tr th:each="locationStat : ${locationStats}">
        <td th:text="${locationStat.state}"></td>
        <td th:text="${locationStat.country}"></td>
        <td th:text="${locationStat.latestTotalCases}">0</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

This is my HomeController

```
package com.project.coronavirustracker.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import java.util.*;
import com.project.coronavirustracker.models.LocationStats;
import com.project.coronavirustracker.services.CoronaVirusDataService;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    CoronaVirusDataService coronaVirusDataService;
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home(Model model) {
        List<LocationStats> allStats = coronaVirusDataService.getAllStats();
        model.addAttribute("locationStats", allStats);
        return "home";
    }
}
```

This is my LocationStats file

```
package com.project.coronavirustracker.models;

public class LocationStats {

    private String state;
    private String country;
    private int latestTotalCases;
    
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
    
    public String getState() {
        return this.state;
    }
    
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    
    public String getCountry() {
        return this.country;
    }
    
    public void setlatestTotalCases(int cases) {
        latestTotalCases = cases;
    }
    
    public int getlatestTotalCases() {
        return this.latestTotalCases;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "LocationStats{" +
                "state='" + state + '\'' +
                ", country='" + country + '\'' +
                ", latestTotalCases=" + latestTotalCases +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And this is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>coronavirus-tracker</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>coronavirus-tracker</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: You need to put in the entire stack trace.  It will have a line number and more specific error message than just `An error happened during template parsing`.

Comment: Your `model` has no attribute `testName`. @see:  `<p th:text="${testName}"></p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that there is no `testName` but this does not generate an error. This will output an empty `<p></p>`.

**The problem is that it cannot find the `latestTotalCases` method.** *(It must start with a capital letter.)*

#### Solution 1

It will fix when you change this method as follows:

```java
public int getLatestTotalCases() {
    return this.latestTotalCases;
}
```

#### Solution 2

If you don't want to change the name of method, **you need to call the method in the html file as follow:**

```html
<td th:text="${locationStat.getlatestTotalCases}">0</td>
```